# Why is "Hello World" script not printing to command prompt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell

I'm a beginner coder using Python 3 and I've come across a weird problem. When I'm activating (if that's the right term) the simple "Hello World" file which only contains:

```
print ("Hello World!")
```

into the command prompt (Windows Powershell); it doesn't print to the command print and it just goes to another prompt as shown below:

```
C:\Users\Samue\OneDrive\Documents\Coding\Python\PyDa> py hello_world.py
C:\Users\Samue\OneDrive\Documents\Coding\Python\PyDa>
```

Sorry if this doesn't make sense but I'm very confused.

Comment: It works for me though. Does `py -c "print('hi')"` work?

Comment: Are you  sure that's powershell and not the old cmd.exe command prompt? Powershell prompts usually start with `PS`.

Comment: I have tried it both in powershell and cmd and worked on both of them. Can you share more information about version of python you're using ? When you execute "py" in cmd what do you get ?

Comment: What does `type hello_world.py` output?

Comment: Are you sure it is added to the PATH variable? When you install python3 for the first time, there is an option you can check to automatically add it to the path variable, or you need to do that manually.

Comment: If `print ("Hello World!")` is the exact content of `hello_world.py` then `py hello_world.py` will print `Hello World!` in both, PowerShell and command prompt. You problem is not reproducible. Especially as `py hello_world.py` does not throw an error, you should double check the content of `hello_world.py`.

Answer (score 1):

Execute

```
python file_name.py
```

in your command prompt

Comment: Okay I think I solved it and I feel incredibly stupid. When I entered python hello_world.py, as suggested by you, I had the correct output of "Hello World". For some reason PS doesn't like me using 'py' instead of 'python' for some reason. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, what kind of PC do you have, but it might be, that the program is executed but instantly closed (maybe too fast for your eye). 
Try:

input()

at the bottom of the script. That makes the program window to stay open until any input is detected.

Greetz

P.S.: If it is not working:: What happens, if you type just "python"?

Answer (score 0):

I'll comment what happened when I entered various commands that you suggested.

Gilch - when I entered what you suggested, this happened:

```
PS C:\Users\Samue\OneDrive\Documents\Coding\Python\PyDa> py -c "print('hi')"
PS C:\Users\Samue\OneDrive\Documents\Coding\Python\PyDa>
```

Nothing printed when I entered the command and PS carried on as if nothing happened. Also this happens when I entered `type hello_world.py`.

```
PS C:\Users\Samue\OneDrive\Documents\Coding\Python\PyDa> type hello_world.py
print ("Hello World")
```

The python version I'm using is Python 3.8.2 and I selected the option to add Python to PATH variable when installing it.
I'm not sure what PC I have but when I included `input()`into the file, the same thing happened.

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't saved the file `hello_world.py` before running it on powershell. Try that.

Comment: This may be an answer, but in OP's case executing `python hello_world.py` instead of `py hello_world.py` is an answer.